# how do i check which tabs is active using jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

how do i check which tabs is active using jquery tabs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try with Index

```
 function getIndex(){
     return $("ul li.ui-state-active").index();
    }
```

It will returns the index of selected li or tab.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to get the active tab during the activate event. I was able to do this using the option active call.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var activeTabId = $(this).tabs('option', 'active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure about this but I think jQuery dynamically assigns a class of 'ui-state-active'

Comment: Correct, jQuery adds the class `ui-state-active` to the active tab.  See http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ with Firebug to see how it works.

Comment: i need to check it programmatically, so i can do actions related to that

Comment: var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // => 0

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like this:

```
$tabContainer.tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.newPanel.is("#TabId")) {
            // do sth here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');
```

Comment: The selected option is delayed by 1 click if you are accessing the value in the activate event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedTabIndex = 0;
jQuery("#tabContainer").tabs({
 select: function(event, ui) { 
  selectedTabIndex = ui.index; 
 }
});
```

**You can use selectedTabIndex in your app**